# Datastream Qt to standard c++ code

Tags: c++, qt, fstream, qdatastream

I created function Qt to read in a binary file, and it works.

[code]

```
    if (fileLoad.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
   {
   QDataStream in(&fileLoad);

   quint8 Variable_8bits;
   quint16 Variable_16bits;
   quint32 Variable_32bits;

   in >> Variable_16bits >> Variable_8bits >> Variable_32bits >> ZeroByte;

   qDebug() <<  Variable_16bits << Variable_8bits << Variable_32bits;

   //Works no extreme conversion necessary as i read input with "set size variables"
   // first 16bits, then 8bits, then 32bits
   // and store it correctly for display
   }
   fileLoad.close(); 
   }
```

So basically I could read in a binary file, using variables of different sizes to access the values in the file (Since I know the format of file structure)

My issue is that, now I need to create the same or similar functionality to a standard c++ function.

Is there a DataStream like Qt for C++
Or do I have to manually load file into buffer,
then read in individual bytes,
do bitwise manipulations to get the correct representation length,
before i display the value
or if there is a simpler method...

whats the way forward...

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the Qt version? You cannot use it on some platform, or what is the problem with Qt in general? Also, do you need to support pre-c++11 toolchains? Have you looked into std::ifstream?

Comment: @2lights Note that `QDataStream` is not for reading and writing just any binary files. It uses its own serialization format, and is meant for reading and writing that. The format is simple, so for *some* types the serialization format is same as just writing raw bytes from memory to file directly, but then the benefit of using `QDataStream` for that purpose is dubious.

Comment: @hyde: x86 fixed mind

Comment: to be more precise in this case on x86 machine omitting `QDataStream` will give different result, since by default `QDataStream` uses big endian and x86 are using small endian.

Answer (score 2):

In standard C++ there is no function/class with functionality similar to [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html).
Pleas note that `QDataStream` class provides support for multiple architectures, it take into account [endians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (by default assumes big endian), different standards of floating point values, it take control of sizes of build in types. (it also supports internalization and externalization of some Qt classes but this issue does not applies to standard C++)
In standard C++ all this platform diversity has to be handled manually (or by library).

Comment: please comment when downvoting I wish to knew why I am wrong (or not)

Comment: I will give you _my_ personal opinion: the OP's issue does not seem to have anything to do with float, "internalization" (for ints?), or "externalization, etc, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) for this simple use case presented as follows below.

However, note that the [8, 16, and 32 bit types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) were only added to the standard in C++11 and on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("example.txt", std::ios::binary);
    uint8_t Variable_8bits; // C++11 and on
    uint16_t Variable_16bits; // C++11 and on
    uint32_t Variable_32bits;  // C++11 and on
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile.read(&Variable_16bits, 2);
        myfile.read(&Variable_8bits, 1);
        myfile.read(&Variable_32bits, 4)
        ...

        std::out << Variable_16bits << Variable_8bits << Variable_32bits;
        myfile.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Unable to open file"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: operators: `>>` `<<` in iostream are for TEXT STREAMS ONLY! Question is about binary streams.

Comment: @MarekR: obsolete, consider removing your comment.

Comment: why did you vote my answer down without comment? Does your solution handles endians, or different standards of floating points?

Comment: @MarekR: why do you think I have downvoted your comment? Also, please stop begging for download reason under my answer. :) But there is no need for endianness in this simple scenario, nor "internalization". I do not even know what "externalization" means. As for the float, that is also moot here since the variables used are integer. Also, please remove your obsolete comment if I may ask.

Comment: Only we are active in this question, there is no other hint who or more important why downvoted my answer. Commenting under my question will not notify anyone about it. http://www.yourdictionary.com/externalization

Comment: Please stop discussing your downvote under my answer. Thank you for your understanding. As for the externalization, it is not even remotely related to QDataStream as it seems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44941/discussion-between-marek-r-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: I don't see how that comment is obsolete.  If I attempted to encode a uint8_t the iostream >>  << operators would consider this a character for ASCII interpretation instead of encoding the actual underlying value which is undesirable behavior when dealing with data streams.